# How to see directory listing inside localhost?

Tags: html, networking, directory, localhost

I use `python -m http.server 8000` to set up a local testing server for my project.

When my project root has `index.html` file then at `http://localhost:8000/` I see content of that `index.html` file there as shown in the image below.

[image]

But when my project root don't have `index.html` file then at `http://localhost:8000/` I see directory listing there as shown in the image below.

[image]

So my question is that **even though if I've `index.html` file at root of the project is there any possible way to see directory listing** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `do_GET()` did the work for me.

[image]